# Mapping stdout to array in memory

Tags: shell

I am working on a shell script right now which I am fairly new to writing, and I currently have an output that is being sent into a qcir text file. What I am trying to do is speed up the time of this script by redirecting the standard output coming from an executable file to the array in memory.

What I am attempting to implement right now is a C function that creates a memory map and then returns the pointer to the start of the map to a variable in the shell script. What I can't seem to figure out is how map the entire output of the executable file being ran.

```
# Out folder is just a file path
QCIR_OUT=${OUTFOLDER}HQ.qcir
n=${#QS}
if [ ${n} -eq 2 ]
then
  GENQBF=exec/genqbf # classic 1 quants
  TIME_GENQBF=$(time ${GENQBF} -I ${I} -R ${R} -J ${J} -S ${S} -P ${P} -k ${k} -F ${QS} -f qcir -o ${QCIR_OUT} -sem ${SEM} -n --fast)
```

From my knowledge, I would think that if I passed the pointer to memory in place of QCIR_OUT as currently shown in the code, that it would not continually update the pointer and just copy to that first address over and over again? I want to avoid having to write to a text file first then to memory as that creates the same problem I am trying to avoid. Any help on how to do this would be great.

Comment: What do you assign to `$QS`?